# Insert image based on page name Atlas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-atlas

I want to add a picture to the layout. Normally I insert the picture file and picture successfully added. But, I want to generate an atlas. I successfully add a dynamic text as title of map based on page name with the syntax:

```
[%District%]
```

When I want to add a dynamic picture the syntax I try :

```
concat('/home/mega/Documents/', 'Bumi Harapan','.png')
```

It is successfuly add a picture, but not dynamic. So, I try this syntax :

```
concat('/home/mega/Documents/', '[%District%]','.png')
```

But the result is red cross. I mean no picture when I run atlas. So, how to add a dynamic picture in atlas based on page name?

Answer (score 5):

I have the answer. By using the syntax :

```
concat('/home/mega/Documents/',("District"),'.png')
```

Answer (score 4):

Or shorter, using pipes (`||`) to concatenate:

```
'/home/mega/Documents/'||District||'.png'
```

Remark: field names can be added without double quotes (even though for clarity, you might want to have them).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Successfull too. Thank you